# String value with dots changed while assignig to "..(class).." - Google Apps Script

Tags: string

I have a problem with assigning a string value containg dots to a variable.
For example, after using this assignment:
**var txt = "company.com.en";**
the variable txt is set to **"company.(class)"**
How to avoid this behaviour, I want to keep this value unchanged.

Comment: Please add what you've tried, and use proper tagging to cover the programming language you've used

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found my problem. It is really silly, but it is a feature of Debug viewer in Google Apps Script. String variables with dots are shown in this way (with ".(class)" string included). The oryginal value of variable remains unchanged. So, case closed.